# SQL matching specific pattern value

Tags: sql-server

I want to join tables `Department` and `Employee` and display the results by matching text value of column `DEPART` and `NAME`.

`DEPART` has a pattern `DEPARTMENT-NAME` so it is possible to just match `-NAME` with values of column `NAME`?

Table `Department`:

| ID | DEPART | DESC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A00 | MARKETING-BOB | MARKETING |
| A01 | MARKETING-BOB | MARKETING |
| A02 | MARKETING-BOB | MARKETING |
| A03 | MARKETING-BOB | MARKETING |

Table `Employee`:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| A00 | STUART, BOB |
| A01 | STUART, BOB |
| A02 | STUART, BOB |
| A03 | STUART, BOB |
| A00 | ELANE, CASTLE JOE |
| A01 | ELANE, CASTLE JOE |
| A02 | ELANE, CASTLE JOE |
| A03 | ELANE, CASTLE JOE |

Result :

| ID | DEPART | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A00 | MARKETING-BOB | STUART, BOB |
| A01 | MARKETING-BOB | STUART, BOB |
| A02 | MARKETING-BOB | STUART, BOB |
| A03 | MARKETING-BOB | STUART, BOB |

Comment: FYI, you'll likely get a comment asking you to convert your image into a text to go in the post. I'd recommend using a markdown table builder site to type it all in. SO users generally don't like image links.

Comment: Please _delete_ the image link and instead include all relevant sample data directly in your question as _text_.

Comment: Storing multiple delimited values in a single column is a common anti-pattern and will result in poor performance; a column should always store a single atomic value.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if the name of the employee is like the last part of the department's name.

```
SELECT 
  dep.ID
, dep.DEPART
, emp.NAME
FROM Employee emp
JOIN Department dep 
  ON dep.ID = emp.ID
 AND emp.NAME LIKE '%, '+RIGHT(dep.DEPART,PATINDEX('%_-%',REVERSE(dep.DEPART)))
```

| ID | DEPART | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A00 | MARKETING-BOB | STUART, BOB |
| A01 | MARKETING-BOB | STUART, BOB |
| A02 | MARKETING-BOB | STUART, BOB |
| A03 | MARKETING-BOB | STUART, BOB |

Answer (score 0):

There's a high risk when you are doing fuzzy matching on potentially ambiguous data (is there more than one Bob?), but the following is a start:

```
DECLARE @Department TABLE(ID VARCHAR(10), DEPART VARCHAR(100), [DESC] VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Department
VALUES
    ('A00', 'MARKETING-BOB', 'MARKETING'),
    ('A01', 'MARKETING-BOB', 'MARKETING'),
    ('A02', 'MARKETING-BOB', 'MARKETING'),
    ('A03', 'MARKETING-BOB', 'MARKETING'),
    ('A02', 'ACCOUNTING-JOE', 'ACCOUNTING'),
    ('A03', 'ACCOUNTING-CASTLE JOE', 'FINANCE')

DECLARE @Employee TABLE(ID VARCHAR(10), NAME VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Employee
VALUES
    ('A00', 'STUART, BOB'),
    ('A01', 'STUART, BOB'),
    ('A02', 'STUART, BOB'),
    ('A03', 'STUART, BOB'),
    ('A00', 'ELANE, CASTLE JOE'),
    ('A01', 'ELANE, CASTLE JOE'),
    ('A02', 'ELANE, CASTLE JOE'),
    ('A03', 'ELANE, CASTLE JOE')

SELECT D.*, E.NAME
FROM @Department D
--CROSS APPLY (SELECT Name = REPLACE(D.DEPART, 'MARKETING-', '')) DN
--CROSS APPLY (SELECT Name = REPLACE(D.DEPART, D.[DESC] + '-', '')) DN
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Name = STUFF(D.DEPART, 1, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', D.DEPART), -1), '')) DN -- More generalized
JOIN @Employee E ON E.ID = D.ID
    --AND E.NAME LIKE ('% ' + DN.Name) -- Match tail following space
    AND E.NAME LIKE ('%, ' + DN.Name) -- Match tail following comma-space
```

Any of the cross apply extracts the name to be matched, and the LIKE attempts a pattern match the tail end of what I presume is '`<last>, <first> <optional-middle>`'.